# how to fetch all the outlinks refrenced on a particular page with page using nutch's parser job

Tags: hbase, nutch, gora

i am using the nutch2.2 and hbase 0.94 and gora 0.4 and when i am executing the steps as follows

```
1.nutch inject seed.txt
2.nutch generate -batchId 231
3.nutch fetch 231
4.nutch parse 231
5.nutch updatedb 231
```

i'll get the html content of a particular page say([http://www.flipkart.com/mens-clothing/t-shirts?otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_men_0_T-Shirts]) but when i am executing the step 4

```
nutch parse 231
```

and see my `webpage` table created in hbase there is a `ol(outlink)` column family but it is empty

if anyone can help it will be good for me if i get all the outlink.

Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure that the fetch phase succeed to download the content of the URL. The webpage is created even the fetch phase get empty content of the URL